# Concrete5 - Call to a member function getRelativePath() on a non-object

Tags: concrete5

(Concrete5)

I have created a custom block using the ***Block Designer*** package.

I receive the following error when **copying** this block onto any page. *I don't receive the error when simply adding it.*

```
Whoops \ Exception \ ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function getRelativePath() on a non-object
```

***I have not altered the code it generated, and none of the fields I created are set to required.***

It specifically highlights line 63, which is:

```
$urls = array('relative' => $pdfdownload_file->getRelativePath());
```

[Please click here for a screenshot of the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a3v9.png)

**I can confirm that I have already tried the following:**

- Uninstalling the block, deleting its folder in the blocks directory,
  and removing it from the blocks table in the database
- Clearing cache
- Re-making the block after deletion

**Additional information**

- Concrete5 Version: 5.7.5.8
- The server is running PHP version  5.4.

Any suggestions, help or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have since resolved the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you implemented a check whether or not the file is found (an object). It seems that the file with this particular block got deleted and it tried to retrieve the relative path from a non-existing file (should be an object, but it's probably "null").

So I build in a check for that for version 2.4.2. You shouldn't have problems like this anymore as of this version of Block Designer.

In case you've got any other issues, you can post support tickets on the concrete5.org site for this product:

https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/block-designer/support

I will get notified by email that you created a ticket/thread. I'm not on SO every day/week, so that's why I missed this in the first place.

Let me know if you have any questions/suggestions/comments!

(the Block Designer developer)